# Picking up application property through cucumber step definition classes

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, cucumber-java

I have a spring boot application with the cucumber and selenium test setup. I am trying to create a UI wrapper for running my cucumber test scenarios. I need to run the selected feature files for which i am using the cucumber.api.cli.Main.run method. 
The problem is i am trying to pick properties through my application.yml files, but my step definition class is not able to pick the properties.

This is how my code looks like -

*RunCukes Class*

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = {"classpath:features"}, 
    plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report","json:target/cucumber.json" }, 
    tags = {"~@ignore"})
    public class RunCukesTest {
    }
```

*The class from where the cucumber feature files are run*

```
      @Service
      public class SeleniumLogic {

      @Autowired
      RunCukesTest runCukes;

        public byte runTest(String[] argv) throws IOException{
            byte result = cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(argv,runCukes.getClass().getClassLoader());
            return result;
           }
         }
```

*The stepdefinition class*

```
        @Component
        public class LoginTestSteps {
          @Autowired
          private LoginPage loginPage;

          @Value("${host.name}")
          private String HOST_NAME;

          @Given("^User is on the login page$")
          public void user_is_on_the_login_page() throws Throwable {
            loginPage.load(HOST_NAME);
          }
       }
```

*Application.yml*

```
     host:
       name: abc.com
```

The HOST_NAME is coming as null in the LoginTestSteps class.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue, my conclusion was that it's not possible to do it like that. The application.yml is a configuration file for Spring, therefore with a Cucumber project you'll have to do your own configuration file format and read from it. You can have a

```
@Value("${host.name:abc.com}")
```

So that abc.com is your default, and you can override it when running the project with a

```
java -jar -Dhost.name=myotherurl.com pathToYourJar/myJar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Component
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
 public class LoginTestSteps {
```